# Display on one img src tag normal images on different formats, and base64 images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using `javascript`  to display images On `HTML` that comes encoded in `base64` from WS .In few cases I get images in `png`, `gif`, `jpg` formats and want to display them in that same `<img src= >` tag.

```
$("#testImage").append("<img src=\"data:image/png;base64," +imgSRC+"">);
```

Where imgSRC is the `base64` image.

1.How can I use one `<img src>` tag to display `base64` images, and normal images on the same img src tag? or to change this tag when I now that returned `imgSRC` is `jpg/png`... image. for example when I get a return value about the image if it `base64` or normal:
`append("<img src=\"data:image/png;base64," +checkImageFormat(imgSRC)+"">);`

How can I by the result of `checkImageFormat(imgSRC)` change the img src tag of current object?

Comment: See this blog post: http://danielmclaren.com/node/90. Basically in FF, yes you can. In IE you'll need to decode the base64 on the server and return it with the correct content-type header.

Comment: Please check this tutorial: http://blog.team-noir.net/2010/03/how-to-use-images-base64-encoded-inline-an-img-tag/

Comment: thanks,those tutorials explaining how to set `base64` images with data attribute...that's fine, What I'm asking is when I have `<img src="data:image/png;base64,imgSRC">` and I getting `imgSRC` as normal image, how to change this line to: `<img src= "imgSRC">` because it an attribute that splited with " , " I can't just delete the attribute because it would look like : `<img src=",imgSRC">`

Comment: 'ata:image/png;base64,imgSRC'.replace(/^(data:image/(png|gif|jpg);)base64,/gi, );

Comment: `ata:`... what is that? If I return value from a function like this: `returnImageType(imgSRC)` how I change the tab of that current `<img src>`

Comment: Why not store the `data:image/png;base64` as part of the image string in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest storing the "data:image/png;base64"-part in the database (or whatever the source may be) as well. That way you wouldn't have to check.

Another solution might be something like:

```
$(function(){

    var $img = $('<img/>')
                   .attr({ src: 'data:image/png;base64,' + imgSrc })
                   .error(function(){
                        $(this).attr({ src: imgSrc }); 
                        //If we end up here the image couldn't be loaded 
                        //If so, we assume that its a jpeg/png/gif
                    });

    $("#testImage").append($img);

});
```